# The Printing Press of Alexandria

Tags: alternate-history, written-material

> *"You think we should come up with a faster way to transcribe this stuff in case some guy tries to burn it all down?"*

Suppose someone at the Royal Library of Alexandria had invented the printing press around the same time Archimedes invented his screw. Or perhaps they were a time traveller, or a demigod son of Hephaestus had a chat with an Oracle – I don't particularly care how it happened, but it did. When I say "printing press," what I'm really talking about is "a way to cheaply print and distribute materials," likely but not necessarily meaning cheap paper that just so happens to have been invented as well as bound books.

I'm not particularly interested in the two-thousand year timeline of such an event, but rather the more immediate societal impacts (although speculation as to the future is likewise welcome). How would the printing press have affected the ancient world? Would it have a profound impact on society and politics throughout the Mediterranean, Mesopotamia, and beyond, or would its influence be limited to the immediate area of the region where it was invented?

Answer (score 6):

How much effort is it to set a page of type and operate the press, compared to simply writing by hand?

I think you are confusing some "easy copying ability" with the reality of a printing press, which is helpful above some number of copies.

If you wanted a single backup, or even 3 copies to distribute, it's still easier to just write it by hand. Maybe invent *carbon paper* or a "ditto" machine for that purpose.  (Anyone here remember the blue ditto copies in school?)

Maybe they could invent a kind of non-photo but chemical etching and masking technique for lithography. A scribe writes (backwards) on a tablet of polished limestone. Then through a series of steps, everything not covered by his writing is etched down.

Comment: Not much effort – a wizard did it. TBH, I'm not writing an alternate history setting, but rather an alternate technological path for a fantasy world whose magic did the opposite of medieval stasis. I wanted to get a feel for how an easier way to copy books would affect ancient Earth so I could extrapolate for my own world. Still, +1 for the useful information regarding the printing press itself. I might apply some of these limitations to the magical printing press.

Comment: You mean a wizard creates the press plates for each page needed?

Comment: I mean a wizard invents an ink-copying spell. Pour ink onto a page enchanted to match a pre-set page and you'll have an exact copy of the original. Eventually this is mechanized, but until then the use is limited as a (magically inclined and talented) scribe is still required. Like I said though, I'm just trying to gauge the effects of something similar on Earth's ancient world so that I can extrapolate to the more fantastical.

Comment: Your original question was not clear: you *do* mean a photocopier, not a printing press.

Comment: No, I *do* mean a printing press. I was curious about the effects of something on Earth, and I want to come up with something similar in a fantasy world.

Comment: In any case, consider the overhead of the particulars in using the method. It will be good for some cases and poor for others. A newspaper web press isn't good for making a single copy, and a desktop xerox machine could not handle a newpaper for a large city.

Comment: This. For printing (as in with a printing press), even today, printer setup costs are a significant fraction of the total cost for a small printing run. Case in point: I recently contacted a printer about a small printing run, and in that particular case, the cost for 20 copies was only 15% higher than the cost for 10 copies. (IOW, if 10 copies cost \$50, then 20 copies cost \$58.)

Answer (score 2):

A printing press is simply a tool and the technology for a 'basic' press design is trivial. The *desire* to spread information is the cultural tool that's needed.

*Initially* a printing press would be a tool of the elite. Considering the Library of Alexandria was supposed to be a repository of all human knowledge, I'd see printing serving two roles - the *spread* of knowledge and 'vanity' books for walls.

Considering the library was lost when it burnt down, copying books and sending them out throughout the empire would mean that should the knowledge there would have a better chance of surviving. Wealthier folks might also want copies of important books and so on.

In a far flung empire *information* has value. Another use of this would be the spread of news - natural disasters, wars, latest fashions, gossip and so on. While the first printed news would be facts and figures, people want a good story. Printed news sheets would be a natural evolution, and *someone*'s gotta read them. Literacy would have greater value, and more people would need to learn to read. In a society with classes, chances are *eventually* the lower classes would need to be somewhat literate, and if there's books around, they'd get *ideas* and want to *improve themselves*.

Well or go all Spartacus on their overlords, but that's another answer.

Wider literacy means a smarter culture, the ability to spread ideas faster, and enhanced technological growth. I suspect it would 'flatten' the societal structure of these places somewhat eventually too.

Answer (score 2):

One important think to remember is that the Library of Alexandria contained mostly of culturally important, but scientifically useless fluff. Poems, epics, historiography, hagiography, religious text, and loads upon loads of philosophical navel-gazing. But the actually rare scrolls that contained useful proto-scientific theories, useful medical knowledge, math, etc were all just copes of copies, and versions of them were already in libraries all over the Eurasia and even as far as Axum (Ethiopia) and western India.

So, reprinting the contents of the Library of Alexandria by itself would not do much to preserve actual knowledge, but it might preserve culture instead.

This might push some thing forward, but it might just as well push some thing backward (for example, most of the texts on medicine held in the LoA were useless, even potentially lethal drivel of the paramagical variety, and losing them actually made way for useful medicine based on evidence and fact to appear.)

Answer (score 0):

Human culture is different now, but human nature is probably the same as in the past. Written "books" existed then, so the idea of public-ation was around. I suspect the rush to print would develop as it did all those years later. Answering your question made me think of this ad: http://www.digibarn.com/collections/movies/digibarn-tv/xerox-monks/

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere scribes are employed, most of them can be replaced by the printing press or a device replicating their function.  The only reason I can think of that it wouldn't catch on is if all text copying in the society is carried out by clergy and it's taken on a meditational aspect that they're unwilling to give up.  Even then, it's likely that the invention of such a device would lead to the emergence of a secular literature tradition unless the authorities went to great lengths to suppress the technology.  (Perhaps even then.)

It stands to reason that technological advancement would be accelerated by eased copying, but not necessarily.  Also, keep in mind that technology is not just pure science.  The Romans were sitting on all the literary and scientific knowledge of the Greeks, but they didn't move natural science forward much at all.  They did, however, make great advancements in construction and social organization. (Leaving open, particularly in the latter case, whether such advancements are at all desirable.)

Comment: "Anywhere scribes are employed, most of them can be replaced by the printing press or a device replicating their function. "  no, one-off copies are still common for letters and notes; bosses still need to dictate the original before it gets typeset. Typesetting is a laborious process in itself.  Scribes don't just duplicate documents: they are employed anywhere you need stuff written or read.

Comment: Scribes was pluralized.  ;)  Rulers and especially privileged scholars will still need a personal scribe of course (I heard from a colleague that David Hume employed 3 young women at a time as scribes, but I don't know if that's reliable.)  But I'm talking about scriberies, places where multiple scribes sit around and copy books and scrolls.

Still, you make a good point.  Unless you're making at least several copies (and maybe a couple dozen), scribe work is easier, less costly, and less time consuming than making the printing blocks to do the job.

Comment: Yes, the details of the process will have everything to do with what becomes of it. In other comments, the OP seems to describe a magic-based xerox machine, but at the same time insists that "printing press" is what he meant. So, *large* set-up cost followed by cheap per-impression cost. (Even if no "plate" is involved. The ink-forming spell is the equivalent in cost model.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy availability of written material will cause a general rise in literacy. If a business man has a filing cabinet with his own personal copies of all the paperwork, he will want to access it at-will and not need a scribe to do that for him.  The boss will be able to write and read more than just ledgers/numbers. But, he may still want someone to "take dictation" for him. This clerical job will become a low-end, low-paid position rather than a contracted expert. IOW, *scribes* will be replaced with *junior clerks*.

Libraries of reference information will be available.

Companies will make catalogs and brochures.  An importer who acquires an interesting item can draw up a flyer and mass produce it, inviting browsers to take a copy and then getting the bright idea to hand them out in public places.

The public toilets will use "junk mail" for wipes. The stuff will be all over the street and compete with horse droppings for the volume of refuse to be scooped up and carted away every day.  So, being already mixed with paper, it will make for better compost without the need to gather straw separately.

This will lead to inspired nicnames for the mass distributed paperwork, and by extension, to the masses of papers used  by the burocracy and government.

Subsistance farmers will question the need for literacy: "why do I need to let my garbage talk to me?" Since the main source of paper he encounters is trash and compost.  But among city dwellers, merchants, and salesmen, it will become universal, as those without it will be handicapped in the field.

But, before the rise of industry, there will still be more farmers than city folks.  With *education* being necessary for city jobs, there will be far less fluidity between the two populations.  **This is setting up for a major cultural divergence.**

Eventually, the "barbarians" will rise up and storm the gates, and the general level of civilization will take a huge step back, as the cities are taken over by those inexperienced with the infrastructure.